# Ubuntu graphics got weird

Tags: graphics, 21.04

I am running Ubuntu 21.04, and it's been running perfectly for about two months. However, when I turned on my PC today, only one monitor worked, and the graphics are weird.

The only available resolution for my screen is 1024x768. Is this the "safe mode" or something that got activated? In that case, how do I turn it off?

Comment: You gave no information that can help to solve the problem. Are you using proprietary drivers for a GPU?

Comment: Check your hdmi cable. I've had this problem and I've fixed it with replacing the cable.

Comment: @Pilot6 Part of the issue is that i dont really know what happend myself. I have a NVDIA GeForce 1080Ti, but i did not really update any drivers or anything prior to the issue appearing. The desktop was acting the same way when i initially intalled ubuntu 20.04, but it got fixed when I upgraded to 21.04.

Comment: @64-bituser I tried swaping both the cables and the monitors. Sadly, no luck.

Comment: So update:
I ended up using grub, 

1. `sudo update-grub`
2. `shutdown -r now`

Then I chose advanced ubuntu, 
There I had 4 options for booting, 5.11.0-38-generic, 5.11.0-38-generic(recovery), 5.11.0-37-generic and 5.11.0-37-generic(recovery).
i ran the 5.11.0-37-generic, and it went back to normal. Then i tried with the 38, and it could not even boot. I havn't tried restarting to see whats the default, but i feel like im creeping up on  a solution.
Probably there has been a update of some sort?

Comment: Probably Nvidia driver didn't build for the last kernel for some reason.

Comment: Here are two possible problems I can think of. 1. Did your computer get suddenly unplugged or de-energized before it could do the shutdown process? This can corrupt essential data, which can mess stuff up real bad in some cases. That's the only time I can think of that you can suddenly have odd problems like this. The only fix I know of is a reinstall. (If your has a battery in it, it is almost completely protected from this.)  2. Were you messing with any essential system files or installing untested odd program enhancers or overclocking before this? That can mess this stuff up too.